# JavaScript Button Toggle: Code Completion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Question is :

We provided some simple JavaScript template code. Your goal is to modify the application so that you can properly toggle the button to switch between an ON state and an OFF state. When the button is on and it is clicked, it turns off and the text within it changes from ON to OFF and vice versa. You are free to add classes and styles, but make sure you leave the element ID's as they are.

```
    import $ from "jquery"
    
    const rootApp = document.getElementById("root");
    rootApp.innerHTML = '<button>ON</button>';
```

so what i've tried

```
import $ from "jquery"

function toggle(button)
{
    switch(button.value)
    {
        case "ON":
            button.value = "OFF";
            break;
        case "OFF":
            button.value = "ON";
            break;
    }
}

const rootApp = document.getElementById("root");
rootApp.innerHTML = '<input type = "button" value = "ON" id = "button" onclick = "toggle();"/>'
```

I am new to JavaScript that's why i am here asking for help.

Comment: We are not here to do an assignment or answer a question that is clearly for homework or something. Show us what you've tried

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4642212) and the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166). Stack Overflow does not accept homework dumps.

Comment: @TomRoman I know but at least one can guide another clueless person in the right direction!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Javascript Button Toggle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   
    <h1>Javascript Button Toggle</h1>
    
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Toggle Button</label>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const btn = document.querySelector('.form-check-input');
        const label = document.querySelector('.form-check-label');
        
        btn.addEventListener('change', function(){
           this.checked ? label.innerHTML = 'Button Turned On' : label.innerHTML = 'Button Turned Off';
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work....

```js
let root = document.getElementById("root");
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#root").click(function(){ 
    if(root.value === "on"){
      root.value="off";
    }
    else{
      root.value="on";
    }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="root" value="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import $ from "jquery" 
const rootApp = document.getElementById("root"); rootApp.innerHTML = '<button>ON</button>';
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#root").click(function(){ 
    if(rootApp.innerHTML = '<button>ON</button>'){
      rootApp.innerHTML = '<button>OFF</button>';
    }else{
      rootApp.innerHTML = '<button>ON</button>';
    }
  });
 });
```

Comment: (@HeathensAirborne: if you think a different answer appropriate, post it as an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

```
import $ from "jquery" 
const rootApp = document.getElementById("root");  rootApp.innerHTML = '<button>ON</button>';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#root").click(function() { 
        (rootApp.innerHTML == '<button>OFF</button>') ? 
            rootApp.innerHTML='<button>ON</button>' : 
            rootApp.innerHTML='<button>OFF</button>';
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import $ from "jquery";
  $(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){

    if ($("#btn").text() == "ON")
    {
      $("#btn").text("OFF")
    }
    else if ($("#btn").text() == "OFF")
    {
      $("#btn").text("ON")
    }

    }
  )
})
const rootApp = document.getElementById("root");
rootApp.innerHTML = '<button id = "btn">ON</button>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import $ from "jquery";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#root").click(function(){
    if (rootApp.innerHTML === '<button>ON</button>'){
      rootApp.innerHTML = '<button>OFF</button>';
    } else {
      rootApp.innerHTML = '<button>ON</button>';
    }
  })
})

const rootApp = document.getElementById("root");
rootApp.innerHTML = '<button>ON</button>';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69411887/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).